# Unable to Install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/2.7.0

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins

Im trying to install plugin in my local elasticsearch setup. while running the following command its giving me failed message.

command: plugin install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/2.7.0

message:
-> Installing elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/2.7.0...
Trying http://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments-2.7.0.zip...
Trying http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/2.7.0/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments-2.7.0.zip...
Trying https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/2.7.0/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments-2.7.0.zip...
Trying https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/archive/2.7.0.zip...
Trying https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/archive/master.zip...
Failed to install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/2.7.0, reason: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information

Answer (score 0):

somehow I resolved it yy downloading the plugin manually and apply it.

Download link for plugin:
http://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments-2.7.0.zip

Install mapper-attachments plugin: open command prompt window under /bin folder and run following command
plugin --install mapper-attachments --url file:///C:\\elasticsearch\elasticsearch-mapper-attachments-2.7.0.zip

Remove plugin: open command prompt window under /bin folder and run following command (if you need to remove any plugin)
plugin --remove mapper-attachments